# Имена функций и неясности с exports

Tags: c, dll

Собрал библиотеку `opus`, далее попробовал экспортировать имена функций через `dumpbin`, получил вот такую непонятную мне вещь:

```
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.15.26726.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file opus.dll

File Type: DLL

  Section contains the following exports for opus.dll

    00000000 characteristics
    FFFFFFFF time date stamp
        0.00 version
           1 ordinal base
          67 number of functions
          67 number of names

    ordinal hint RVA      name

          1    0 00001980 opus_decode = @ILT+2416(_opus_decode)
          2    1 00002320 opus_decode_float = @ILT+4880(_opus_decode_float)
          3    2 00001FC0 opus_decoder_create = @ILT+4016(_opus_decoder_create)
          4    3 00001560 opus_decoder_ctl = @ILT+1360(_opus_decoder_ctl)
          5    4 00002630 opus_decoder_destroy = @ILT+5664(_opus_decoder_destroy)
          6    5 000025B0 opus_decoder_get_nb_samples = @ILT+5536(_opus_decoder_get_nb_samples)
          7    6 00002270 opus_decoder_get_size = @ILT+4704(_opus_decoder_get_size)
          8    7 00002550 opus_decoder_init = @ILT+5440(_opus_decoder_init)
          9    8 000016D0 opus_encode = @ILT+1728(_opus_encode)
         10    9 00001910 opus_encode_float = @ILT+2304(_opus_encode_float)
         11    A 00002100 opus_encoder_create = @ILT+4336(_opus_encoder_create)
         12    B 00001790 opus_encoder_ctl = @ILT+1920(_opus_encoder_ctl)
         13    C 00002530 opus_encoder_destroy = @ILT+5408(_opus_encoder_destroy)
         14    D 000019B0 opus_encoder_get_size = @ILT+2464(_opus_encoder_get_size)
         15    E 00002260 opus_encoder_init = @ILT+4688(_opus_encoder_init)
         16    F 00001060 opus_get_version_string = @ILT+80(_opus_get_version_string)
         17   10 00001F00 opus_multistream_decode = @ILT+3824(_opus_multistream_decode)
         18   11 00002930 opus_multistream_decode_float = @ILT+6432(_opus_multistream_decode_float)
         19   12 000017C0 opus_multistream_decoder_create = @ILT+1968(_opus_multistream_decoder_create)
         20   13 00001B20 opus_multistream_decoder_ctl = @ILT+2832(_opus_multistream_decoder_ctl)
         21   14 00001A50 opus_multistream_decoder_destroy = @ILT+2624(_opus_multistream_decoder_destroy)
         22   15 00001EC0 opus_multistream_decoder_get_size = @ILT+3760(_opus_multistream_decoder_get_size)
         23   16 000017A0 opus_multistream_decoder_init = @ILT+1936(_opus_multistream_decoder_init)
         24   17 00002040 opus_multistream_encode = @ILT+4144(_opus_multistream_encode)
         25   18 00001DD0 opus_multistream_encode_float = @ILT+3520(_opus_multistream_encode_float)
         26   19 00001C00 opus_multistream_encoder_create = @ILT+3056(_opus_multistream_encoder_create)
         27   1A 000015E0 opus_multistream_encoder_ctl = @ILT+1488(_opus_multistream_encoder_ctl)
         28   1B 00001050 opus_multistream_encoder_destroy = @ILT+64(_opus_multistream_encoder_destroy)
         29   1C 00001590 opus_multistream_encoder_get_size = @ILT+1408(_opus_multistream_encoder_get_size)
         30   1D 000019E0 opus_multistream_encoder_init = @ILT+2512(_opus_multistream_encoder_init)
         31   1E 00001F30 opus_multistream_packet_pad = @ILT+3872(_opus_multistream_packet_pad)
         32   1F 00001F40 opus_multistream_packet_unpad = @ILT+3888(_opus_multistream_packet_unpad)
         33   20 000021F0 opus_multistream_surround_encoder_create = @ILT+4576(_opus_multistream_surround_encoder_create)
         34   21 00001360 opus_multistream_surround_encoder_get_size = @ILT+848(_opus_multistream_surround_encoder_get_size)
         35   22 00001970 opus_multistream_surround_encoder_init = @ILT+2400(_opus_multistream_surround_encoder_init)
         36   23 000027B0 opus_packet_get_bandwidth = @ILT+6048(_opus_packet_get_bandwidth)
         37   24 00001AF0 opus_packet_get_nb_channels = @ILT+2784(_opus_packet_get_nb_channels)
         38   25 000011F0 opus_packet_get_nb_frames = @ILT+480(_opus_packet_get_nb_frames)
         39   26 000016E0 opus_packet_get_nb_samples = @ILT+1744(_opus_packet_get_nb_samples)
         40   27 00001660 opus_packet_get_samples_per_frame = @ILT+1616(_opus_packet_get_samples_per_frame)
         41   28 00001DB0 opus_packet_pad = @ILT+3488(_opus_packet_pad)
         42   29 00001E30 opus_packet_parse = @ILT+3616(_opus_packet_parse)
         43   2A 00001C20 opus_packet_unpad = @ILT+3088(_opus_packet_unpad)
         44   2B 000010D0 opus_pcm_soft_clip = @ILT+192(_opus_pcm_soft_clip)
         45   2C 00001570 opus_projection_ambisonics_encoder_create = @ILT+1376(_opus_projection_ambisonics_encoder_create)
         46   2D 00001350 opus_projection_ambisonics_encoder_get_size = @ILT+832(_opus_projection_ambisonics_encoder_get_size)
         47   2E 000017B0 opus_projection_ambisonics_encoder_init = @ILT+1952(_opus_projection_ambisonics_encoder_init)
         48   2F 00001990 opus_projection_decode = @ILT+2432(_opus_projection_decode)
         49   30 000016A0 opus_projection_decode_float = @ILT+1680(_opus_projection_decode_float)
         50   31 00001440 opus_projection_decoder_create = @ILT+1072(_opus_projection_decoder_create)
         51   32 00002720 opus_projection_decoder_ctl = @ILT+5904(_opus_projection_decoder_ctl)
         52   33 00001C90 opus_projection_decoder_destroy = @ILT+3200(_opus_projection_decoder_destroy)
         53   34 000012B0 opus_projection_decoder_get_size = @ILT+672(_opus_projection_decoder_get_size)
         54   35 00002580 opus_projection_decoder_init = @ILT+5488(_opus_projection_decoder_init)
         55   36 000020B0 opus_projection_encode = @ILT+4256(_opus_projection_encode)
         56   37 00001400 opus_projection_encode_float = @ILT+1008(_opus_projection_encode_float)
         57   38 00001710 opus_projection_encoder_ctl = @ILT+1792(_opus_projection_encoder_ctl)
         58   39 00001010 opus_projection_encoder_destroy = @ILT+0(_opus_projection_encoder_destroy)
         59   3A 00001860 opus_repacketizer_cat = @ILT+2128(_opus_repacketizer_cat)
         60   3B 00001110 opus_repacketizer_create = @ILT+256(_opus_repacketizer_create)
         61   3C 00001D50 opus_repacketizer_destroy = @ILT+3392(_opus_repacketizer_destroy)
         62   3D 00002820 opus_repacketizer_get_nb_frames = @ILT+6160(_opus_repacketizer_get_nb_frames)
         63   3E 000020C0 opus_repacketizer_get_size = @ILT+4272(_opus_repacketizer_get_size)
         64   3F 000029C0 opus_repacketizer_init = @ILT+6576(_opus_repacketizer_init)
         65   40 000012F0 opus_repacketizer_out = @ILT+736(_opus_repacketizer_out)
         66   41 00001130 opus_repacketizer_out_range = @ILT+288(_opus_repacketizer_out_range)
         67   42 00001410 opus_strerror = @ILT+1024(_opus_strerror)

  Summary

        1000 .00cfg
        8000 .data
        1000 .gfids
        1000 .idata
        1000 .msvcjmc
       10000 .rdata
        3000 .reloc
        1000 .rsrc
       85000 .text
```

Что именно не ясного, так это присутствие подчеркивания у имен функций который написан в скобках?

Сама проблема обнаружилась при попытке найти адрес функции `opus_encoder_destroy`, всегда возвращает `0`.

Это применено какое-то декорирование имен, или это какой-то баг или еще что?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Видимо библиотека была собрана VS и использовалось [декорирование имен по-умолчанию](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/name-decoration?view=vs-2017):

```
Calling convention                          | extern "C" or .c file | .cpp, .cxx or /TP
C naming convention (__cdecl)               | _test                 | ?test@@ZAXXZ
Fastcall naming convention (__fastcall)     | @test@0               | ?test@@YIXXZ
Standard Call naming convention (__stdcall) | _test@0               | ?test@@YGXXZ
Vectorcall naming convention (__vectorcall) | test@@0               | ?test@@YQXXZ
```

Если нужны конкретные имена, или имена не нужны, то следует писать `.def` файл со скриптом для линкера.